# strcat char concatenation trouble

Tags: arduino-ide

Still don't understand about char concatenation.

```
void setup() {

  testCounter(3);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

char testCounter(int countx){
  char a[10];
  strcpy(a, "COUNTER: ");
  strcat(a, printDigits(countx));
  return a;
}

char printDigits(int digits){
  char a[3];
  if(digits < 10) {
    strcpy(a, "0");
    sprintf(a,"%d",digits);
  } else {
    sprintf(a,"%d",digits);
  }
  return a;
}
```

Error:  *invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]* in `testCounter` line:

```
strcat(a, printDigits(countx));
```

Don't understand this part of error.

`printDigits` function return char, so... `strcat` should be work. But why still error?

Please help...

Answer (score 2):

```c++
char printDigits(int digits){
```

You are telling the compiler you will return **one** character.

```c++
 char a[3];
```

`a` is three characters. Thus the declaration doesn't match.

---

You could change the declaration to:

```c++
char * printDigits(int digits){
```

But even that would be bad because `a` would go out of scope after the function returns.

---

```c++
 char a[3];
```

That's a little short for putting an integer into. An integer might be 5 characters, plus possibly a minus sign, and you need a trailing "null" at the end. Seven bytes would be safer.

---

The simplest way of doing what you seem to be wanting is:

```c++
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  testCounter(3);
}

void loop() {
}

char testCounter(int countx){
  char a[15];
  sprintf (a, "COUNTER: %02d", countx);
  Serial.println (a);
}
```

---

Also, here:

```c++
  if(digits < 10) {
    strcpy(a, "0");
    sprintf(a,"%d",digits);
  } else {
```

That won't work because you are putting "0" into `a` and then **overwriting** it with `sprintf`.

---

> `printDigits` function return `char`, so... `strcat` should be work. But why still error?

Look at the prototype for `strcat`:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/

It expects `char *` not `char`. They are different things. One is a pointer, one isn't.